# Generating shortcode and displaying in admin area

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

Basically I'm writing a plugin to create sliders. Upon installing this plugin, it creates a custom post type called 'sliders' and populate them with ACF.

I've also created shortcode to display slider on pages/post. Shortcode works like this -> [slider id=12] , and this will display slider with the id of 12.

What I'm trying to find a way of displaying the shortcode in the admin area which users can just copy instead of looking for ID number. Here's the example.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: you want to copy your short code and admin can past in post and page then its showing slider am I right?

Comment: @Jinesh , yes. Shortcode is already being generated. I just need a way to display the shortcode somewhere in admin area where users can copy and use it.

Comment: have this shortcode for wordpress latest version?

Comment: I think if you are using wordpress 5.2 than you need to create custom block to achieve your reuqirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `sliders` is your CPT slug, you can use `manage_sliders_posts_columns` to add column head.

```
add_filter('manage_sliders_posts_columns', 'wpso_custom_columns_head');
function wpso_custom_columns_head($defaults) {
    $defaults['shortcode']  = 'Shortcode';
    return $defaults;
}
```

After adding column heading, now we need to add content for the column. Use `manage_sliders_posts_custom_column` hook. Using this you can echo shortcode.

```
add_action('manage_sliders_posts_custom_column', 'wpso_custom_columns_content', 10, 2);
function wpso_custom_columns_content( $column_name, $post_ID ) {
    if ( 'shortcode' === $column_name ) {
        echo '[shortcodename id="' . $post_ID . '"]';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Display Custom field label/title

```
add_filter( "manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns", array( $this, 'manage_columns' ) );

public function manage_columns( $columns ) {
        $new_columns              = array();
        $new_columns['cb']        = '<input type="checkbox" />';
        $new_columns['title']     = esc_html__( 'Slider Name', 'wp-quiz' );
        $new_columns['shortcode'] = esc_html__( 'Shortcode', 'wp-quiz' );
        $new_columns['date']      = esc_html__( 'Date', 'wp-quiz' );

        return $new_columns;
    }
```

Display Shortcode of each slider

```
add_action( "manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column", array( $this, 'manage_column_data' ), 10, 2 );



  public function manage_column_data( $column, $post_id ) {
        echo '<div class="field"><input type="text" readonly value="' . esc_html( '[wp_slider id=&quot;' . $post_id() . '&quot;]' ) . '" onClick="this.select();" style="width:100%;"></div>';
    }
```

**You can also check from codex.wordpress.org from below link**
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_custom_column